# Is it worth slipstreaming updates?

Tags: windows, reinstall

I've got a massive task ahead of me, which is to boot, nuke, and reinstall Windows on 40 identical PCs.

*Unfortunately* that means I'm going to have to go through the 200 or so updates that Windows is going to want to do, and on 40 PCs that could easily take a week.

It also means installing the different versions of Windows the PCs were running before the wipe.

So I'm wondering, is it more efficient to slipstream updates for Vista, 7, and 8.1 onto the respective media, then deploy, virtualise each OS, update and capture (this one bothers me, because of the duplicate SID issues), or install and update everything separately?

Comment: It is what the majority of IT personal actually do.

Comment: If you Sysprep-generalize the machine before capturing it, it installs like a new OS but with all the updates and programs.

Answer (score -1):

I can't speak for Windows 8, but with Vista and 7 it's not terribly difficult to create an administrator installation of Windows (press shift +f2 when prompted to start the out of the box experience wizard), install all your updates and software (don't enter licence keys unless your software is volume licensed), and then use sysprep to generalize the image (creates a new sid for each machine it's deployed to) and shut the machine down. Once you do that you can then use ghost if you have it or clonezilla to clone the image to each machine. It will take you probably a day to build the image and have Windows update finish, and then an hour to take the image and then an hour to deploy the image and go through the oobe and join your domain with a fully patched machine.

Some caveats:
Windows can only be sysprepped 3 times and on more than one occasion I've received a machine from an OEM with all the activations used. So it may be wise to just start from scratch. 
I suggest capturing an image before you sysprep so that if you screw up after you sysprep but before you capture the image you don't have to start over. It's very easy to boot off the hard disk instead of the CloneZilla media.
If you use clonezilla start with your machine with the smallest drive. It's easier to go from small to big than to clone a larger drive to a smaller one.